# Symfony HWIOAuthBundle - How to disbable automatic logout?

Tags: symfony, timeout, logout, hwioauthbundle

I'm using [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) for users to log in with their social account. And once a user is logged in it's logged out after 30 minutes or so.

Any idea how to disable that so they stay logged in forever?

Comment: for me the solution was in security.yml
`security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `cookie_lifetime` in your configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        #lifetime in seconds
        cookie_lifetime: 3600
```

See [Framework configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime) for more info. If you want to keep your users permanently logged, you may also want to look at implementing a "remember me" functionality, see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Use remember_me from your firewall or just add cookie_lifetime to 1 year, depends of your design pattern

```
 firewalls:
     secured_area:   
         remember_me:
            lifetime: 31536000 #1 year
```